# How to use ElemMatch to compare List<DataTime> in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to deal with `{Document} is not supported.` exception in C#?

Want to convert below MongoDB query to C# code:

```
db.Data.find({
    "searchData": "Abc",
    "modifyDates": {
        $elemMatch:{
            $gte: ISODate("2022-07-01T07:00:00Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2022-07-04T07:00:00Z")
        }
    }
})
```

Model in C#:

```
public class MyData
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string searchData { get; set; };

    public List<DateTime> modifyDates
    {
        get => _modifyDates ?? new List<DateTime> { lastChange };
        set => _modifyDates = value?.OrderBy(d => d).ToList();
    }
    private List<DateTime> _modifyDates;

}
```

MongoDB C# builder (both cases not working):

```
// start and end dates for filtering records
var start = = DateTime.Parse("01/06/2022");
var end = = DateTime.Parse("10/06/2022");

// case1:
var builder = Builders<MyData>.Filter;
var filter = builder.ElemMatch(f => f.modifyDates, d => d >= start && d <= end);

// case2:
var builder = Builders<MyData>.Filter;
var filter = builder.ElemMatch(f => f.modifyDates, Builders<DateTime>.Filter
    .Where(d => d >= start && d <= end));

// no matter from case1/2, there is exception `{Document} is not supported.`
return await Collection.Find(filter);
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: you should clean up your question, the code you provided won't be compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you can't use expression income argument `d` for this particular case. I think this case is just not implemented yet in the driver. You can use a raw bson document form instead typed:

```
        var builder = Builders<MyData>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.ElemMatch(f => f.modifyDates, new BsonDocument { { "$gte", start }, { "$lte", end } });
```